# Pattern for extracting price from web source htm

Tags: r, pattern-matching

I got huge source string of html page. How can I extract 23,995 as a string from below ?

```
.....ml">&pound;23,995</a>.....
```

I tried sth like:

```
 "(^([:&:])pound[:;:][0-9][0-9],[0-9][0-9][0-9])"
```

but does not work. Thr price will always be 5-digit number.

Comment: There is a better way to deal with html content.

Answer (score 0):

```
library(stringr)
str_match(text, ";(.*)<")[2]
[1] "23,995"
```

But you should really be using a package like 'XML' for this kind of work.

Comment: If you recommend the OP use the XML package, I recommend posting an example using the XML package. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
library(stringr)
str_match(text, "&pound;(\\d{2},\\d{3})<")[2]
```

Comment: thank you but the above returns NA. I ended up so far with this:
'library(stringr)'
'str_extract_all(A, "ÂŁ[0-9][0-9],[0-9][0-9][0-9]")'

somehow this is the representation of the pound mark

Comment: @user2710469, It should work for the html text you posted in your question. But if the html has unicode character instead of the `&pound;` in it, you can just replace it in my pattern string with that character.